# Replace a child control with other control at runtime WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am having a stack panel, in which I am adding controls at run time.

how can I replace  the particular control with another control at same position?

Thanks

Comment: Guys please make sure you add comment before down voting :D

Answer (score 0):

`StackPanel` has a `Children` property which is a [`UIElementCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) object. If you're adding things at runtime, I assume you're already calling the `Add` method on that collection. You can call `RemoveAt` on that collection to remove a specific one and then `Insert` to put your new object into that same index.